# Auto-populate specific columns on excel based on selected menu using vba

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to auto-populate the next columns based on the selected dropdown option of the 1st column on excel.

[image]

Below sample of the initial code that I thought but it appears my approach is incorrect.

```
Private Sub WorksheetStore_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim intCol As Integer

    intCol = shtStoreGroup.Range("A")
    If Not IsEmpty(Target.value) And intCol > 1 And Target.Columns.Count = 1 And Target.Column = intCol And Target.Row > Start_Row Then
        For i = Target.Row To Target.Row + Target.Rows.Count - 1
            If shtStoreGroup.Columns(intCol).Rows(i).value = "Create" Then
                shtStoreGroup.Columns(intCol + 2).Rows(i).value = "N/A"
                shtStoreGroup.Columns(intCol + 3).Rows(i).value = "Test"
        Next i
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I suppose "WorksheetStore" is the name of your worksheet. But you should do things, when your combobox value changes. e.g.: `Private Sub comboBoxName_Change() ... End Sub`

Comment: or maybe when it losts focus: `Private Sub comboBoxName_LostFocus() ... End Sub`

Comment: you may want to add more details about how many sheets are involved, their name, what should start happening where and what this should trigger where,...

Comment: @Tretom actually the worksheet name is shtStoreGroup. i just thought i need to define the subroutine "WorksheetStore_Change" that will be executed whenever there is an action/change on the menu dropdown.

Comment: @user3598756 this is the only worksheet. the goal is if select create on the drop-down menu of the columns there will be specific values that will populate the next columns (e.g Store Group ID = N/A, Group Name = MyGroup, Description = Test Group, etc.). Same goes if i select the Delete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you're after this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal target As Range)

    If Not ValidateTarget(target, 2) Then Exit Sub '<-- exit if function validating 'Target' returns 'False'

    On Error GoTo EXITSUB ' <-- be sure to handle possible errors properly
    Application.EnableEvents = False '<--| disable events handling not to run this sub on top of itself
    Select Case UCase(target.Value)
        Case "CREATE"
            target.Offset(, 2).Value = "N/A"
            target.Offset(, 3).Value = "Test"
        Case "DELETE"
            target.Offset(, 2).Value = "???"
            target.Offset(, 3).Value = "Test??"
    End Select

EXITSUB:
    Application.EnableEvents = True '<--| restore events handling
End Sub

Function ValidateTarget(target As Range, Start_Row As Long) As Boolean
    With target
        If .columns.Count > 1 Then Exit Function
        If .Column <> 1 Then Exit Function
        If .Row <= Start_Row Then Exit Function
        If IsEmpty(.Value) Then Exit Function
        ValidateTarget = True
    End With
End Function
```

place the above code in the relevant worksheet ("shtStoreGroup"?) code pane, and NOT in a normal module code pane

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need worksheet_change() function

with a combobox named cbTest I would do it like

```
Option Explicit
Sub fill()

    cbTest.AddItem ("Value1")
    cbTest.AddItem ("Value2")

End Sub

Private Sub cbTest_Change()
    Select Case cbTest.Value
    Case "Value1"
        Cells(1, 1).Value = "Test"
    Case "Value2"
        Cells(1, 2).Value = "Test2"
    End Select
End Sub
```